# how to make length restriction on string::getline

Tags: c++, string, c++11

> istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);

for string::getline, there is no parameter that can prevent overflow by restricting number of characters. Maybe cin.getline(str,length) can make up this problem, but I want to know if there are other ways using string::getline.

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) extendes the string as needed, it will never cause an overflow. That's the nice thing about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), it can be added to very easily.

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function doesn't have a parameter for a max length limit. `std::string` is dynamic in nature, it grows in size as it is appended to. The max limit of `std::getline()` is [`std::string::max_size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size).

If you want to limit the line length, you have to use the [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because there is no need for it, since [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) manages the string as needed, in order to prevent an overflow.

Moreover remember that [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) has the ability to grow in size easily.